# using GPG key in Gajim without passphrase

Tags: gpg, gajim

I would like to use gpg key with Gajim (jabber client) without a passphrase. I have generated my gpg key without a passphrase (or with an empty passphrase, I don't know which - I just just pressed enter)

I have configured gajim to use my gpg keys, but now when Gajim starts, it asks me for my passphrase, and I need just to press enter.

I am wondering, is there a way to completely get rid of this passphrase dialog? Can I either generate the gpg key without a passphrase entirely, or can I tell gajim not to ask for the empty passphrase (or remember it) ?

Comment: Did you try to use the GPG-Agent for managing the passphrase? It’s a checkbox in the account’s configuration. (Didn’t try it, though.)

Answer (score 1):

You really should use either gpg-agent and/or the similar program provided by Gnome. This way your system will ask for the passphrase only once per boot.